# Using vuetify in single .html page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a personal project where I'm trying to avoid a full npm build process and instead work within a single `.html` file that uses Vue 3 and Vuetify. Here's the full HTML (basically you can drop it into a file, open it in a browser, and see what I'm seeing):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.4.3/dist/vuetify.min.css">
  <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js",
          "vuetify": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.4.3/vuetify.esm.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="d in numbers" :key="d">
          <td>{{ d }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </v-table>
  </div>

  <script type="module">
    import { createApp, ref } from 'vue'
    import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

    const vuetify = createVuetify()
    const app = createApp({
      setup() {
        const numbers = ref([4, 5, 6])
        return { numbers }
      }
    })

    app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I can see that Vue starts up, I can see that the Vuetify assets are being fetched properly, but I get an error in the console that I think means something's happening out of order:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "d" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <VTable> 
  at <App>
```

My guess is that the template is trying to render somehow before the `setup()` script populates `data`? Is what I'm trying to do possible?

One other thing that seems odd is that when I don't try to use data and instead just create a simple table with `v-table`, eg.

```html
<v-table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1C1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</v-table>
```

the rendered output is just `<table> Col 1 Col 2 R1C1 R1C2 </table>`, but there are no errors in the console. Worth noting that if I remove Vuetify from the mix and just use regular table tags, my table is created properly. It seems to happen only when Vuetify tries to render the `v-table` component.

Comment: Please, add all relevant code to the question, so it could be understandable without navigating to external links. Currently the line that causes the warning (v-for) is unavailable. From what I see, the problem is that you use DOM for component template, and <tr> is allowed only inside <table> in html

Comment: Updated the post with the full HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put Vue template code into the `<div id="app">` directly, it will be processed by the browser before Vue can get to it. When table elements like thead, tbody, etc. are used outside a table, the browser kicks them out, leaving you with this:

```html
<v-table>{{ d }}</v-table>
```

Since `d` from the `v-for` was removed along with the tr, you end up with a warning and a broken table.

---

There are two ways to resolve the issue, either move the template code into Vue setup and leave the app mount point empty:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

and

```html
  <script type="module">
    ...
    const app = createApp({
      template: `
        <v-table>
          rest of the table code...
        </v-table>
      `,
      setup() {
        const numbers = ref([4, 5, 6])
        return { numbers }
      }
    })
    ...
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a table element instead of the `v-table` and have Vue replace it later on using the `is` attribute:

```html
  <div id="app">
    <table is="vue:v-table">
      rest of the table code...
    </table>
  </div>
```

There are other issues when not using templates, have a look at the [in-DOM Template Parsing Caveats section of the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#element-placement-restrictions)

Comment: That was it! For quick coding I went with the `is=` attribute but lots of good stuff I didn't know in there.